# Check if shortcut is present on homescreen as in normal mobile apps

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to get the user to 'install' the shortcut icon to a webpage and use it as an icon to the PWA.

I am wondering if any of you had a chance to somehow discover if the user installed the shortcut on home screeen?

This is an interesting case, because when developing on Android or such one has access to such information, on the other hand I don't recall browser giving that information away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beforeinstallprompt will only fire if the user has NOT installed the PWA
**First**: Use that to check if installed

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {

  // If you get inside here, the PWA is not installed

});
```

Example code here

### https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners

**Second**: If you are showing your own deferred prompt like the examples at the link above, you can listen to know if they close that without adding to home screen (A2HS)

```
// Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
this.deferredPrompt.userChoice
  .then((choiceResult) => {

    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        // User said yes to your A2HS
    } else {
        this.deferredPromptRejected = true;
    }

  });
```

**Third**: You can check if your PWA is running as a standalone

```
function isRunningStandalone() {
  return (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);
}
```